# Firefox autofill text field corruption

Tags: firefox, debug

Occasionally, when I am typing into a text field on a website, or the search box in the browser, Firefox 89.0.2 on Linux Mint will display a drop-down that is corrupted.  The corruption appears to be black and white, with tiny boxes of varying size, like a small graphic of tiny black and white rectangles.  I've only started noticing it in the past month or two, and it doesn't happen more than a few times a week.  Usually, canceling and typing to make it show again fixes it immediately.  Has anyone else had any experiences with this?  What is the best way to gather more information about what could be causing it.  A quick search for corruption browser text field and a few other similar searches didn't come up with anything that looked related.

Comment: What add-ons do you have installed and do any by their nature autofill fields?  A screenshot of what you are talking about might help identify the behavior you describe.  "Has anyone else had any experiences with this?" - No; But without a screenshot of what you are seeing exactly, you might miss that one person who has.  *Problems like this are either extremely widespread or fairly rare* a screenshot is worth a 1000 words.

Comment: I don't know of any extensions that do anything with autofill fields.  I have Firefox Multi-Account Containers, Google search link fix, HTTPS everywhere, NoScript, and uBlock Origin.  I'll have to try to be more vigilant the next time it happens.  Like I said, it's easy to fix, so I usually just do the thing to fix it automatically.